# Whys is tsc not recognized even after installing typescript globally

Tags: javascript, typescript

Instead of explaining all details, here is the picture of my problem.
[image: here is te image]

Comment: did you add npm global installation folder path to `Path` in windows `Environment Variables` ?  like `C:\Users\{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: yes, it is in my path in my windows environment variable. But still not working.

Comment: it's strange, check if `tsc.cmd` file present in that folder? if it's present, check by opening fresh command prompt.

Comment: "Instead of explaining all the details, here's a picture"  Please *take the time* to add the contents of the picture to your question, **as text**, so it can be indexed and read.  It will also preserve the long-term value of your question.  What happens when the image link goes dead?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I solved the problem for myself. For me, my npm confix prefix was set to '/usr/local ' which should be 'c:/Users/{yourname}/AppData/Roaming/npm' on windows. '/usr/local ' should be on Linux.
I changed npm config using command:  'npm config set prefix c:/Users/{yourname}/AppData/Roaming/npm'. Then tsc worked.

You can also add a new path variable of '/usr/local' which should work fine but things should be same as it was before.

Comment: So how did you install your node.js / npm? Because it seems to be the source of the problem. I know it's already solved but it's not going to hurt to know why you've been in this situation.

Comment: Yeah, my friend helped me to solve that. I had followed many tutorials on nodejs from various YouTubers. Some of them were using windows and some of them were using macos. I might have done something wrong while following those tutorials

Comment: I didn't put my tsc path into my environment. Thanku all for your time.